# Centralizar verticalmente um label no StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

Estou tentando centralizar verticalmente um `label` dentro de um `StackPanel`. Já defini o atributo `VerticalAlignment="Center"` mas não notei diferença no posicionamento vertical, como pode ser visto na imagem abaixo. Ou seja, o label continua alinhado ao topo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue também o `XAML`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="FoxCcoManagerMainScreen.FixedHeaderControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FoxCcoManagerMainScreen"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Width="405" Height="77.5">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Rectangle Height="45" Stroke="Black" Fill="#FFFF7400"/>
        <StackPanel Height="30" Background="#FF1B1B1B">
            <Label x:Name="label" Content="Home" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontSize="13.333" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa alinhar no centro o `StackPanel` segurando seu rótulo. Seu rótulo está alinhado centralmente se você prestar muita atenção. O `StackPanel` segurando o rótulo não está alinhado.